# C custom rewrite rule

Tags: c, string, replace, url-rewriting

I have a hard C program for which I do not understand the requirements. The question states the following:

---

Write a program that reads a word, a number k and several lines, each with a rewrite rule: a capital letter, = and a string. Rewriting a word replaces each letter that has a rule with a given string; other characters don't change. Print a string obtained by rewriting the initial word k times.

**Example:**

```
B+AxB 
2
A=AB
B=A
```

prints

```
AB+ABAxAB
```

Thank you very much, I would really appreciate some help since I don't even understand the requirement. I hope someone can point me to the right direction.

Comment: It's a very interesting program, what have you done so far? post that here please.

Comment: I don't understand how he got that output. Could you explain it to me?

Comment: The number in the second line tells you how many times you apply the rules(A=AB, B=A) in this case B+AxB at the first replacement expands to A+ABxA, and then in the second replacement AB+ABAxAB

Comment: @DGomez write this as an answer and I will accept it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number in the second line tells you how many times you apply the rules
`A=AB` and `B=A` in this case `B+AxB` at the first replacement expands to `A+ABxA`, and then in the second replacement `AB+ABAxAB`

Answer (score 2):

Since the file has this content

```
B+AxB
2
A=AB
B=A
```

I suppose the `2` stands for the number of times to apply the rules, so here we go, first we have

```
B+AxB
```

then `A` should be substituted by `AB`, so

```
B+(A->AB)xB -> B+ABxB
(B->A)+ABx(B->A) -> A+ABxA
```

then a second time

```
(A->AB)+(A->AB)Bx(A->AB) -> AB+ABBxAB
AB+AB(B->A)xA -> AB+ABAxAB
```

note that the replacement should be made only on the original occurrence.